# The most efficient way to handle visitor/user statistics that I want to catch and display?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am building a link directory style web application. For simplicity all of the following are examples. On my website I have 10 categories. Each category has it's own page and each page has 100 links in a table format. Each link has many columns like name, id, url, etc but the focus of this question deals with the "time last viewed" column. It will display a default text if the user/visitor has never clicked the link however if the link has been clicked by the user prior to the visit it will display the time/date the user last visited that link.

The way I have it set up is when the user clicks the link they are sent to another page/script (using GET method. link 1 is appended with ?rid=1) I use a switch contruct. (Case value is 1 from $_GET execute code block) this code block is where i need the user statistics caputuring to happen. Once the function runs and both captures and stores the visit statistics info the user is sent to the requested resource via header location. So the next time to user sees the list of links on the category page the link they visited will now display the time they visited it.

On my production site i have up to 1000 links. If they clicked each link it would say next to each link the last time they clicked it. Important to include users will be logged in when clicking each link.

How would you go about doing this? Store the info in a cookie or in the database? As there are 1000 links there could be 1000 different values. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a lot of data so you can do both, store in the database as well as store in a cookie. Ideally for performance, you should retrieve from the cookie first and then retrieve from the database if the cookie doesn't contain any user information pertaining to that link. Depending on your performance requirements and the amount of traffic you anticipate, you can use database storage, in-memory storage and asynchronous updates.

- database updates are instant but can impact overall performance and page load times
- in-memory caching such as apc gives best performance but data needs to be synchronised to the database
- asynchronous updates are great for balancing out performance hits because you can register a view from the client side using JavaScript after the page has loaded, rather than during php execution on server side.

Personally I would use all 3 if possible because it gives a good platform for future development.